# SSRS 2008 (not R2) parameter only returns the first name in list

Tags: reporting-services

SSRS parameter only returns the first name in list.

I am running SQL Server 2008 (NOT R2) Reporting Services

I have a Parameter called @Signature in my Dataset.  The query for this parameter pulls a list of names from a field called “fullname.”
The properties of the parameter are “Get values from a query” and the Available Values are set to
    Dataset  = Signature
    Value Field = fullname
    Label field = fullname

I placed the “fullname” field in my report, but when I select any name from the list in my parameter, it always returns the first value in the parameter list.  I am pretty certain that is because the expression for this field is set to the following:  =First(Fields!fullname.Value, "Signature")  Because I have 2 datasets, I have to distinquish with “Signature.”

I need the “fullname” field to populate with the name I select in my parameter.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisLatta. This opens a bigger problem for me.  There is actually one more field that needs to display called "filename" I tried the following but had errors.  =IIf(Parameters!Signature.Value = (Fields!fullname.Value, "Signature"), (Fields!filename.Value, "Signature"))  Do you know how I might write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the name selected in your parameter, use the expression:

```
=Parameters!Signature.Label
```